# Generic Dijkstra's

Tags: java, dijkstra

I'm currently working a Dijkstras Algorithm problem and hit a brick wall. My assignment is I'm in a one story building with X by Y amount of rooms. Each room has a cost to go to it. On the borders are several exits and I have to find the shortest path to one of those exits from a randomly placed starting point.

Before I explain the problem I'm having, I'll explain some of my code.

I created a class called room to store each cost and adjacency as such:

```
static class room implements Comparable<room> {

    int value;
    int i;
    int k;
    PriorityQueue<room> adj = new PriorityQueue<room>();
    double distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    room(int i, int k, int v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.i = i;
        this.value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(room o) {
        return this.value - o.value;
    }
```

the adjacencies of everyone room consists of only rooms directly North, East, South and West.

```
static void adjacent(room[][] field, int row, int column) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k <= column; k++) {
            if (field[i][k + 1] != null) {
                field[i][k].adj.add(field[i][k + 1]);
            }
            if (field[i][k - 1] != null) {
                field[i][k].adj.add(field[i][k - 1]);
            }
            if (field[i + 1][k] != null) {
                field[i][k].adj.add(field[i + 1][k]);
            }
            if (field[i - 1][k] != null) {
                field[i][k].adj.add(field[i - 1][k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

My variable start is the first room I begin in. And I created a method that will poll it's adjacencies one at a time and send it to this method.

```
 static void closestExit(room s) {
    while (s.adj.size() != 0) {
        LinkedList<room> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(s.adj.poll());
        q.peek().distance = q.peek().value;
        while (q.size() != 0) {
            if (q.peekLast().adj.size() == 0)//if adj list is empty then remove it from the list or if last in queue is an X remove it
            {
                backtrack(q);
            } else if (q.peekLast().value == 'X') {
                q.removeLast();
            } else if (q.peekLast().adj.peek().value == 'X' || q.peekLast().adj.peek().value == 'S')//if head of adj list is S or X then it removes it
            {
                q.peekLast().adj.remove();
            } else if (q.peekLast().distance > shortpath)//checks distance to see if it went over dpath. 
            {
                backtrack(q);
            } else if (checkExit(q.peekLast().adj))//if exit is in adj list then record the distance
            {
                shortpath = q.peekLast().distance;       
                backtrack(q);
            } else {
                if (!(q.contains(q.peekLast().adj.peek())))//checks to see if the list already has this room in it
                {
                    q.peekLast().adj.peek().distance = q.peekLast().adj.peek().value + q.peekLast().distance;
                    q.add(q.peekLast().adj.poll());
                } else {
                    q.peekLast().adj.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (shortpath == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
        shortpath = -1;
    }

}
```

The problem that is occurring is that while I'm removing adjacencies and manipulating distances from one of start's adjacencies it seems to be effecting the other adjacencies of start. So if I'm traversing through the north room of start and I end up reaching a room I went to from the west room of start, that room's adjacencies are going to be 0 because the west room cleared it already.

I don't understand why this is happening when I'm sending each adjacency of start as it's own entity into the method. Any insight will be helpful.

PS "start" and field are local variable in the main class NOT a class variable.

Comment: I don't understand the setup of your algorithm. Why is there a priority queue of adjacent rooms from each room? There should just need to be an immutable list of adjacencies. On the other hand, in the actual shortest path finding function, you need to have a way of getting the "smallest distance" potential node, but I don't see anything you're doing to get the smallest one.